# Binomial Expansion

Tags: binomial-theorem

If $f(x)= \dfrac{1}{(2x+1)} + \dfrac{4}{(x-2)} + \dfrac{8}{(x-2)^2}$ show that when $x$ is sufficiently small for $x^3$ and higher powers to be neglected, $f(x)= 1- x + 5x^2$
How do I do this without using the Maclaurin expansion.

Comment: Binomial? In which sense?

Comment: What do you mean by not using the Maclaurin expansion? You are basically asking for the first three terms of the Maclaurin expansion. Maybe you just mean: without computing $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ for all $x$?

Comment: I do not recommend the following approach, but it will work, and doesn't use any Calculus: combine the three fractions into a single quotient of two polynomials, and then work out as much of the quotient as you need, by polynomial long division. Actually, you could do that on the three fractions individually, and then add the results of the three divisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT : you have $x$ sufficiently small ie you can use the following two expansions :

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+ x + x^2 + O(x^3)$$

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + O(x^3)$$

Make sure you transform what you have in the above forms before expanding.

EDIT : If you really want to use the binomial theorem which is :
$$(c+y)^\alpha = c^\alpha + \alpha y c^{\alpha-1} + \frac12\alpha(\alpha-1)y^2 c^{\alpha-2} + O(y^3)$$

Then go ahead substituting $c = 1$, $y = -x$ and $\alpha = -1$ and you will get the above geometric series. That said you can just use it directly without the need of using my hints above.

Comment: And how did you get these expansions?

Comment: @user140161 : The first is the geometric expansion. The second is simply the square of the first one.

Comment: We don't have geometric expansions in our course. Or the Maclaurin series. This is supposed to be done using the binomial theorem

Comment: @user140161 : binomial theorem will give exactly the same. I'll edit so that you see.